# Why I do not get line numbers in exception stack trace if I have PDB and symbols loaded?

Tags: exception, debugging, release, stack-trace

I have a solution with several projects. The solution is in Release mode with no optimization and with pdb files generated. While running Unit Tests i get exceptions but the stack trace does not contains the line numbers. At the modules window I can see that the current assembly is not optimized and that it has symbols loaded.

Just to note that I'm checking the stacktrace inside the debugger at a breakpoint where the exception is caugth.

Thanks in advance mates.